# How to get smallest element in list using lambda in python?

Tags: python, lambda

In python I have a list of elements, and I want to get the smallest element based on its lambda value. Something like this

```
def g(list, f):
    min = list[0]
    for i in list:
        if f(i) < f(max):
             min = i
    return min
```

How can this be done in 1 line using lambda functions?

Thanks

Comment: Well, just use `min()`. Anyway, what's the "lambda value" you're talking about?

Comment: `min(myList, key=f)`

Comment: Take more care in choosing your variable names. Do _not_ use names of builtins as variables.

Comment: I presume `f(i)<f(max)` is supposed to be `f(i)<f(min)`?

Answer (score 6):

using reduce:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: min(x, y, key=f), lst)
```

But you can also use `min` directly:

```
min(lst, key=f)
```

because `min` can be used to compare 2 elements or an iterable of elements

Answer (score 2):

```py
min=list(filter(lambda x: (x >= i), list))[0]
```

We are iterating over the list and making sure that we are taking only the elements that that this condition will return true,
than because filter can only work on an array this will return us a list with one element so we will save it as the element at `pace0`

Comment: did you compare performance between the filter and lambda versus the min function

Answer (score 1):

You can just say

```
min(l, key=f)
```

Where `l` is your list, and `f` is your comparator function

Also, do not name your variable `list`, do not name your variable `min`, etc.